# How to make nicEditor snaplet? (Several questions)

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

The example below defines a snaplet to bind nicEditor to textarea. The following questions are not only related to the example below, but probably they are related to some other similar cases..

1. Can a newbie follow the instructions below (how to clarify)?
2. How to make the example use less steps or otherwise simpler? (Is it possible with approximately the same content as below?)
3. This used interpreted splice. If possible, should a snaplet provide compiled splices, too?
4. A snaplet probably could give a default handler or couple of handlers to typical situations. And handlers could be defined in the "SnapNic.hs" below. Some callback mechanism to users, then?

--

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- | This module defines nicEditor snaplet, just a short example to show,
-- how snaplets can be defined together with splices.
-- License: BSD3. 
-- Here are hopefully easy instructions, how to use or try:
-- 
-- 1. Make a directory, we'll use "netry" below, go there.
--  Initialize a project, e.g. "snap init default".
-- 2. Copy this file to netry/src-directory as SnapNic.hs.
-- 3. Add "import SnapNic" to Site.hs and to Application.hs
-- 4. Add ", _niced :: Snaplet Nicsnap" to data App in Application.hs 
-- 
-- 5. Add "n <- nestSnaplet "niced" niced nicsnapInit" to 
--    app :: SnapletInit App App in Site.hs. 
-- 6. Add "addNicEditSplices n" to the same function as in step 5.
-- 7. Change the return-line of the same function as in step 5: 
--      "return $ App h s a n" 
--    that is, add "n" into the end. We need this because of step 4.
-- 
-- 8. Make route, e.g. ", ("/netext",   with auth handleNEtext)" to
--    routes-function in Site.hs
-- 
-- 9. And then add handler into Site.hs:
--    handleNEtext :: Handler App v ()
--    handleNEtext = method GET handleForm <|> method POST handleFormSubmit
--      where
--       handleForm = render "textedit"
--       handleFormSubmit = do 
--        p <- getParam "ots"
--        writeText "Submitting text from textarea...\n"
--        writeText (T.pack (show p))
-- 
-- 10. Last, add the following 2 templates to "netry/snaplets/heist/templates".
--    (This could be made simpler, but this works as an example of apply-tag.)
--    textedit.tpl:
--      <apply template="base">
--         <apply template="_textedit" />
--      </apply>
--    _textedit.tpl:
--       <h2>Your nic editor</h2>
--         <form method="post" action="netext">
--           <neTA/>
--           <button name="ne" value="ne" type="Submit">Send text</button>
--         </form>
--         <neScript/>
-- 
-- 11. Compile everything "cabal install -fdevelopment". After that, 
--     if everything compiled, "netry -p 8000", start your browser and go
--     to "localhost:8000/netext".
-- 
-- TODO! This could use the config-files at least for some parameters, and more
-- tags,please. Tags could use some attributes (for example, size parameters
-- could be given as attributes of tags)...
-- 
module SnapNic 
  ( Nicsnap (..)
  , nicsnapInit
  , addNicEditSplices
  ) where

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import           Control.Lens   (makeLenses, view, (^.))
import qualified Data.Text as T (Text, append, pack)
import           Data.Maybe     (fromJust, fromMaybe)
import           Snap.Core      (MonadSnap)
import           Snap.Snaplet   (Snaplet
                                , makeSnaplet
                                , snapletValue
                                , SnapletInit
                                , Initializer
                                )
import           Snap.Snaplet.Heist     (HasHeist, addSplices)
import qualified Text.XmlHtml as X      (Node (Element, TextNode))
import qualified Heist.Interpreted as I (Splice)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- | Nicsnap has fields that can be used to set some basic properties.
-- The editor can have a title and its size can be set. Javascript can be
-- local or remote.
data Nicsnap = Nicsnap
  { _nicsnap  :: T.Text       -- title
  , _areaSize :: (Int,Int)    -- rows, cols
  , _areaRef  :: T.Text       -- how to apply nicEditors? 
  -- (This may not be sufficient in order to refer in some other way, TODO!)
  , _localR   :: Maybe T.Text -- local route to nicEdit.js
  , _webR     :: T.Text       -- route to nicEdit's javascript source. 
  }

makeLenses ''Nicsnap          -- makes webR and other lenses


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- | Configurations are given here. This could use config-files...
-- What other things to configure?
-- If you want to make a local copy of the nicEdit, then add a static route
-- to the "routes"-function. 
nicsnapInit :: SnapletInit b Nicsnap
nicsnapInit = makeSnaplet "nicsnap" "NicEditor snaplet " Nothing $ do
   let m  = "Nic editor title"
       aS = (20,80)::(Int,Int) -- rows, cols
       aR = "nicEditors.allTextAreas" -- TODO! We need to be able to tell,
       -- which textareas have editors in a page.
       lR = Nothing 
       -- lR = Just "/nicEdit.js" 
       -- If localR is nothing, then webR is used with the following addr.
       wR = "http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"
   return $ Nicsnap m aS aR lR wR

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- | Internal, this makes the script-tag.
-- Input could be e.g. txt = "/nicEdit.js"
srcElem :: T.Text -> X.Node
srcElem txt = X.Element "script" 
   [("src",txt),("type","text/javascript")] []

-- | Internal, this makes the script-tag. At the moment this changes all
-- textareas to niceditors, if the example input below is used. TODO!...
-- Input could be e.g.  txt = "nicEditors.allTextAreas"
srcOnLoad :: T.Text -> X.Node
srcOnLoad txt = X.Element "script" [("type","text/javascript")] 
   [X.TextNode (T.append (T.append "bkLib.onDomLoaded(" txt) ");")] 


-- | Internal, used to define "divs", where we give a label and size to 
-- textarea. Also ids and names.
-- TODO! ids and names could be parameters.
divLabelTX :: T.Text -> T.Text -> T.Text -> X.Node
divLabelTX title r c =  X.Element "div" [("class", "required")]
   [ X.Element "label" [("for","ots")] 
        [X.TextNode title]
   , X.Element "textarea" 
        [("id","ots"), ("name","ots"), ("cols",c), ("rows",r)] 
        [X.TextNode " "]
   ]

-- | Internal, this can be used in splice-definition.
-- TODO! ids and names could be parameters, too.
nicTextAreaAdd :: MonadSnap m => T.Text -> (Int,Int) -> I.Splice m
nicTextAreaAdd title (r,c) = return [divLabelTX 
  title
  (T.pack . show $ r) 
  (T.pack . show $ c)]

-- | Add script-tags to web page with splice that tell, what javascript
-- library to use... 
nicEditAdd :: MonadSnap m => T.Text -> T.Text -> I.Splice m
nicEditAdd src edElems = return (srcElem src : [srcOnLoad edElems])

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- | Get the route to the javascript library that is applied (either local
-- library or construct a link to a web address).
nicRoute :: Nicsnap -> T.Text
nicRoute ns = let mlR = ns ^. localR in fromMaybe (ns ^. webR) mlR

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- | neTextAreaTag and neScripTag are used in addSplices to define the tags
-- to be used in templates.
-- What other tags could be useful? Maybe a way to add a nicEditor directly
-- with one or more button bind to it ("send", "clear", etc). TODO!
neTextAreaTag = "neTA"     :: T.Text
neScriptTag   = "neScript" :: T.Text

-- | Make the tags to be used in templates. At the moment, only the above
-- tags are defined. 
addNicEditSplices :: HasHeist b => Snaplet Nicsnap -> Initializer b v ()
addNicEditSplices n = let m = view snapletValue n in addSplices
  [(neTextAreaTag, nicTextAreaAdd (m ^. nicsnap) (m ^. areaSize))
  ,(neScriptTag,   nicEditAdd (nicRoute m) (m ^. areaRef) )
  ]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a newbie, so I can't answer your first question, but I've got some thoughts and answers to some of the others.  First of all, if you really want this to be a serious snaplet (either for instructional purposes or real use) you should probably make this into a cabal project.  That would eliminate step 2 from your instructions.  Next, snaplets can define their own routes.  You can do that in your initializer by calling the [addRoutes](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/0.11.2/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet.html#v%3aaddRoutes) function.  This would eliminate step 8.  Snaplets can also provide their own filesystem resources that will be copied into any project that uses it.  You could use this feature to eliminate step 10, as well as provide default config files.  For more information on how to do this, look at the [filesystem data and automatic installation](http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/snaplets-tutorial#filesystem-data-and-automatic-installation) section at the end of the snaplet tutorial.

Currently, [snaplet-postgresql-simple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snaplet-postgresql-simple) is probably the best example on hackage of how to use most of the features that snaplets have to offer.  If you want to make this a really robust general purpose snaplet for other people to use, then you should definitely include both interpreted and compiled splices.  I recently added some [new functions](https://github.com/snapframework/snap/blob/master/src/Snap/Snaplet/Heist/Generic.hs) to the snap package that make it easier to write generic snaplets that automatically work in either compiled or interpreted splice mode.  That code isn't on hackage yet, but I'll probably be releasing it soon.

I have also been working on [another snaplet](https://github.com/Soostone/snaplet-actionlog) that makes much more comprehensive use of most of the features of the snaplet API.  Unlike snaplet-postgresql-simple, this snaplet defines templates and splices.  It is still under development, but already demonstrates most of the features.  The remaining work will be mostly just polish and robustness.

Comment: Thanks again! I had to read filesystem data section several times and had some hard time with cabal. Now it seems to install and I can use just like other libraries.

Comment: And continuing, the next questions in line are, what to do with this package after I have done some cleaning. (Should this put to github?) Another question is that now the route requires /-char at the end of address. How to make this accept also an address without ending /-char?

Comment: If you think other people can benefit from this, then the usual approach is to put it on github and hackage.  I can't answer the second question without more information.

Comment: I think it's great that you're playing with snaplets, but I might also make a side note that this probably isn't the best application for a snaplet.  It looks to me like you could do most of this more flexibly inside a template just by using the `<bind>` tag.  I tend to write snaplets for things that require more haskell code and can't be done in templates alone.