# How to get addRoutes to work in a snaplet (changing api's, heist 0.12)?

Tags: haskell-snap-framework

In 
[How to make nicEditor snaplet? (Several questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462941/how-to-make-niceditor-snaplet-several-questions)
I followed the hints and put `addRoutes` into the snaplet initializer and it worked. After updating snap and heist (0.12) modules to newer, I have some difficulties with `addRoutes`. If `addRoutes` is removed from `nicsnapInit` (in the snaplet example) and put into `routes`-function in Application.hs, the route is initialized at the same time as other routes in App and route is found.

However, if `addRoutes` is in `nicsnapInit`, server just says

```
no handler accepted "/netext".
```

This looks like the route is not added.

How to use `addRoutes` in snaplet initializers at the moment (heist 0.12)?

---

Learned almost right away that [Snap Framework: Custom snaplet handler won't render template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493052/snap-framework-custom-snaplet-handler-wont-render-template) has almost similar problem. There `addTemplates` was used just before `addRoutes`. After similar changes this seems to work, that is, with line

```
addTemplates h ""
```

where h is the parameter at

```
nicsnapInit :: HasHeist b => Snaplet (Heist b) -> SnapletInit b Nicsnap
```

and corresponding change to the application initializer.

This changes the url to "niced/netext", i.e. first the snaplet name and then the route that is defined in the snaplet.

Is it possible to add only the "/netext"-part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nestSnaplet "" nicsnap $ nicsnapInit ...`.  The first parameter to nestSnaplet is not the snaplet's name.  It is the URL that all the snaplet's routes are relative to.